# jQuery code to add / remove classes depending on the button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

#### What the code does

What the JQuery code does is add / remove classes on div's elsewhere on the page, depending on the button clicked.

Button 1 clicked → add class `showModule` to `div`s with class `Module1` (remove `showModule` class from all other `div`s)

Button 2 clicked → add class `showModule` to `div`s with class `Module2` (remove `showmodule` from all other `div`s)

However, there are tons of redundancies? How can I make this much more concise?

Code below the longer explanation

---

CSS to make sections appear or dissappear:

```
.x-section.hideModule {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  padding:0;
  transition: opacity .8s ease;
}

.x-section.showModule {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 100%;
    transition: opacity .8s ease;
}
```

These classes get added or removed based on clicking behaviour.

When someone clicks the button for 'module 1' the button itself gets a class added, but relevant div further down the page get the class `showModule` added, and the class `hideModule` is removed. In addition other div's have the class `showModule` removed and the class `hideModule` added. Thus, only the relevant content is visible to the user.

**can the code below be recoded / simplified for less redundancies**

So my JQuery code to achieve this works beautifully, but this code has so much redundancy in it... There must be a much smarter way to achieve this? Please be kind... absolute coding newbie here.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(function () {
    // when button 1 is clicked, set button 1 to active,
    // others to not active
    $(".module1Btn").click(function () {
      $(".module1Btn").addClass("moduleBtnActive")
      $(".module2Btn").removeClass("moduleBtnActive")
      $(".module3Btn").removeClass("moduleBtnActive")
      // and show module 1, hide others
      $(".module1").addClass("showModule")
      $(".module2").addClass("hideModule")
      $(".module3").addClass("hideModule")
      $(".module1").removeClass("hideModule")
      $(".module2").removeClass("showModule")
      $(".module3").removeClass("showModule")
    })
    // when button 2 is clicked, set button 2 to active,
    // others to not active
    $(".module2Btn").click(function () {
      $(".module2Btn").addClass("moduleBtnActive")
      $(".module1Btn").removeClass("moduleBtnActive")
      $(".module3Btn").removeClass("moduleBtnActive")
      // and show module 2, hide others
      $(".module2").addClass("showModule")
      $(".module1").addClass("hideModule")
      $(".module3").addClass("hideModule")
      $(".module2").removeClass("hideModule")
      $(".module1").removeClass("showModule")
      $(".module3").removeClass("showModule")
    })
    $(".module3Btn").click(function () {
      // when button 3 is clicked, set button 3 to active,
      // others to not active
      $(".module3Btn").addClass("moduleBtnActive")
      $(".module1Btn").removeClass("moduleBtnActive")
      $(".module2Btn").removeClass("moduleBtnActive")
      // and show module 3, hide others
      $(".module3").addClass("showModule")
      $(".module2").addClass("hideModule")
      $(".module1").addClass("hideModule")
      $(".module3").removeClass("hideModule")
      $(".module2").removeClass("showModule")
      $(".module1").removeClass("showModule")
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: There seems to be a lot of redundancy in your request to remove redundancies. 

Answer (score 2):

You added classes to mark the differences, all you need to do is add classes that mark the commonalities as well.

```
<div class="module-btn" data-visibile-class="module-1" />
<div class="module-btn" data-visibile-class="module-2" />
<div class="module-btn" data-visibile-class="module-3" />

<div class="module-content module-1" />
<div class="module-content module-2" />
<div class="module-content module-3" />
```

```
$('.module-btn').click(() => {
  $('.module-btn.active').removeClass('active')
  const clickedButton = $(this)
  clickedButton.addClass('active')
  const visibleClass  = clickedButton.attr('data-visible-class')
  $('.module-content:not(.' + visibleClass + ')').addClass('hide').removeClass('show')
  $('.module-content.' + visibleClass).addClass('show').removeClass('hide')
})
```

Not tested at all, but hopefully you get the idea...